# Parsing Swagger JSON data and storing it in .net class

Tags: arrays, json, dynamic-arrays, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to parse Swagger data from the JSON I get from {service}/swagger/docs/v1 into dynamically generated .NET class.

The problem I am facing is that different APIs can have different number of parameters and operations. How do I dynamically parse Swagger JSON data for different services?

My end result should be list of all APIs and it's operations in a variable on which I can perform search easily.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find an answer for this? Today I wanted to do the same thing, so I used the AutoRest open source project from MSFT, https://github.com/Azure/autorest. While it looks like it's designed for generating client code (code to consume the API documented by your swagger document), at some point on the way producing this code it had to of done exactly what you asked in your question - parse the Swagger file and understand the operations, inputs and outputs the API supports.

In fact we can get at this information - AutoRest publically exposes this information.

So use nuget to install AutoRest. Then add a reference to AutoRest.core and AutoRest.Model.Swagger. So far I've just simply gone for:

```
using Microsoft.Rest.Generator;
using Microsoft.Rest.Generator.Utilities;
using System.IO;
```

...

```
        var settings = new Settings();
        settings.Modeler = "Swagger";

        var mfs = new MemoryFileSystem();
        mfs.WriteFile("AutoRest.json", File.ReadAllText("AutoRest.json"));
        mfs.WriteFile("Swagger.json", File.ReadAllText("Swagger.json"));
        settings.FileSystem = mfs;
        var b = System.IO.File.Exists("AutoRest.json");

        settings.Input = "Swagger.json";

        Modeler modeler = Microsoft.Rest.Generator.Extensibility.ExtensionsLoader.GetModeler(settings);
        Microsoft.Rest.Generator.ClientModel.ServiceClient serviceClient;
        try
        {
            serviceClient = modeler.Build();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Something nasty hit the fan: {0}", exception.Message));
        }
```

The swagger document you want to parse is called Swagger.json and is in your bin directory. The AutoRest.json file you can grab from their GitHub (https://github.com/Azure/autorest/tree/master/AutoRest/AutoRest.Core.Tests/Resource). I'm not 100% sure how it's used, but it seems it's needed to inform the tool about what is supports. Both JSON files need to be in your bin.

The serviceClient object is what you want. It will contain information about the methods, model types, method groups

Let me know if this works. You can try it with their resource files. I used their ExtensionLoaderTests for reference when I was playing around(https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/AutoRest/AutoRest.Core.Tests/ExtensionsLoaderTests.cs).

(Also thank you to the Denis, an author of AutoRest)

Comment: HI @friartuck, I am not able to find the nuget packages. Can you please update the answer when you have time?

Answer (score -2):

If still a question you can use **Swagger Parser** library:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser
as simple as:

```
// parse a swagger description from the petstore and get the result
SwaggerParseResult result = new OpenAPIParser().readLocation("https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json", null, null);
```